# premature deletion of pointer held by shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

A class of mine has destructor like:

```
virtual ~MergeMove()
{

    mergeIndex1=-1; // for debugging
    mergeIndex2=-1; // for debugging
}
```

Another class contains a member of type `boost::shared_ptr<Move>` , where `Move` is the baseclass of `MergeMove`. The destructor of `Move` is virtual.

```
class Forest
{
     vector< boost::shared_ptr<Move> > moves;
     ....
}
```

At the point my code crashes, I find that `moves.at(i)->mergeIndex1=-1` .
I'm pretty sure only the destructor can set it to `-1`. Also, valgrind reports some invalid reads.
I have been debugging the problem for more than 24 hours ... with no luck.
I think I have followed the standard guidelines for using shared_ptrs.

1) Always assigned the result of new to a shared_ptr immediately. There are no raw pointers.

2) while passing `this` to a function expecting `shared_ptr`, I used `shared_from_this()` . But I have passed `*this` to some functions taking a reference - I guess it should be fine.

What could be the problem? I am using gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1)
Are there some known bugs? How can I debug it further?

here is the output from valgrind ... which confirms premature deletion:

```
==28242== Invalid read of size 8
==28242==    at 0x5CAAFA: boost::shared_ptr<Symbol>::get() const (shared_ptr.hpp:424)
==28242==    by 0x5E0160: bool boost::operator==<Symbol, Symbol>(boost::shared_ptr<Symbol> const&, boost::shared_ptr<Symbol> const&) (shared_ptr.hpp:481)
==28242==    by 0x5C5851: MergeMove::applyMove(Forest&) (mcmcParsh.h:1022)
==28242==    by 0x5C43C4: Forest::applyMove(int) (mcmcParsh.h:704)
==28242==    by 0x5C4408: Forest::applyMoveToClone(int) (mcmcParsh.h:709)
==28242==    by 0x5C46C1: Forest::genMoveAndApplyToClone() (mcmcParsh.h:753)
==28242==    by 0x5C64D3: BeamSearch::sampleNextBeam() (mcmcParsh.h:1414)
==28242==    by 0x5C65F9: BeamSearch::runBeamSearch() (mcmcParsh.h:1431)
==28242==    by 0x58F2CA: find_most_violated_constraint_marginrescaling(pattern, label, structmodel*, struct_learn_parm*) (svm_struct_api.cpp:221)
==28242==    by 0x5AC5FE: find_most_violated_constraint(svector**, double*, example*, svector*, long, structmodel*, struct_learn_parm*, double*, double*, long*) (svm_struct_learn.cpp:944)
==28242==    by 0x5AB339: svm_learn_struct_joint(sample, struct_learn_parm*, learn_parm*, kernel_parm*, structmodel*, int) (svm_struct_learn.cpp:719)
==28242==    by 0x5A62F5: main (svm_struct_main.cpp:81)
==28242==  Address 0x31461568 is 152 bytes inside a block of size 200 free'd
==28242==    at 0x4C27A83: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
==28242==    by 0x5C4EC0: MergeMove::~MergeMove() (mcmcParsh.h:971)
==28242==    by 0x60A0BA: void boost::checked_delete<MergeMove>(MergeMove*) (checked_delete.hpp:34)
==28242==    by 0x63A299: boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<MergeMove>::dispose() (sp_counted_impl.hpp:78)
==28242==    by 0x5AFBD9: boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release() (sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145)
 ==28242==    by 0x5AFC9C: boost::detail::shared_count::~shared_count() (shared_count.hpp:217)
==28242==    by 0x5C367D: boost::shared_ptr<Move>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.hpp:169)
==28242==    by 0x61EA5F: void std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<Move> >(boost::shared_ptr<Move>*) (stl_construct.h:83)
==28242==    by 0x615EFF: void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<boost::shared_ptr<Move>*>(boost::shared_ptr<Move>*, boost::shared_ptr<Move>*) (stl_construct.h:93)
==28242==    by 0x609806: void std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<Move>*>(boost::shared_ptr<Move>*, boost::shared_ptr<Move>*) (stl_construct.h:116)
==28242==    by 0x5F57C4: void std::_Destroy<boost::shared_ptr<Move>*, boost::shared_ptr<Move> >(boost::shared_ptr<Move>*, boost::shared_ptr<Move>*, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Move> >&) (stl_construct.h:142)
==28242==    by 0x5DF807: std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Move>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Move> > >::~vector() (stl_vector.h:313)
```

---

here is the code for Base class

```
class Move
{
 private:
double costDelta;
double transProb;
LOSS_MAP_TYPE addMap;
LOSS_MAP_TYPE delMap;
protected:
bool transProbSet;
bool applied;


void setTransProbFromDelta()
{
    transProb=exp(costDelta/10.0);
    transProbSet=true;
}

public:
typedef  boost::shared_ptr<Move> SPtr;

virtual Move::SPtr clone()=0;
void applylabelMapDelta( LOSS_MAP_TYPE & lab)
{
    subtractLabelmap(delMap,lab);

    appendLabelmap(addMap,lab);
}

typedef SupportComplex<Floor> SCENE_TYPE;
void resetCostDelta()
{
    costDelta=0;
}

void adjustCostDeltaForNodeAddition(Symbol::Ptr newNode, Forest & cfor);
void adjustCostDeltaForNodeRemoval(Symbol::Ptr remNode, Forest & cfor);
virtual void adjustCostDeltaByLossForNodeAddition(Symbol::Ptr newNode, Forest & cfor);
virtual void adjustCostDeltaByLossForNodeRemoval(Symbol::Ptr remNode, Forest & cfor);

virtual string toString()=0;
double getCostDelta()
{
    return costDelta;
}

Move()
{
    transProb=false;
    costDelta=0;
    applied=false;
}

virtual bool moveCreationSucceded()
{
    return true;
}


virtual void applyMove(Forest & cfor)=0;
/**
 * 
 * @return Q(f',f) where f' is the forest which will be generated when
 * applyMove is called on f
 */
virtual double getTransitionProbUnnormalized()
{
    assert(transProbSet);
    return transProb;
}

virtual bool isInvalidatedOnDeletion(int index)=0;
virtual bool handleMove(int oldIndex, int newIndex)=0;
virtual ~Move() {}
};
```

`Symbol::Ptr` is also a shared_ptr

```
class MergeMove: public Move
{
int mergeIndex1,mergeIndex2;
Symbol::Ptr mergeNode1,mergeNode2; // store nodes also for additional safety check
RulePtr mergeRule;
NonTerminal_SPtr mergeResult;

public:
virtual Move::SPtr clone()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<MergeMove> ret (new MergeMove(*this));
    cerr<<"mmclon:"<<toString()<<":"<<this<<"->"<<ret.get()<<endl;
    assert(ret->mergeIndex1!=-1);
    assert(ret->mergeIndex2!=-1);
    return ret;
}
typedef  boost::shared_ptr<MergeMove> SPtr;

virtual bool moveCreationSucceded()
{
    return (mergeResult!=NULL);
}

vector<Symbol::Ptr> marshalParams(RulePtr mergeRule)
{
    vector<Symbol::Ptr> nodes;
    if(mergeRule->getChildrenTypes().at(0)==string(typeid(*mergeNode1).name()))
    {
          nodes.push_back(mergeNode1);
          nodes.push_back(mergeNode2);
    }
    else
    {            
        assert(mergeRule->getChildrenTypes().at(0)==string(typeid(*mergeNode2).name()));
          nodes.push_back(mergeNode2);
          nodes.push_back(mergeNode1);            
    }
    return nodes;
}

virtual ~MergeMove()
{

    if(moveCreationSucceded())
            cerr<<"mmdel:"<<toString()<<":"<<this<<endl;
    mergeIndex1=-1; // for debugging
    mergeIndex2=-1; // for debugging
}

MergeMove(Forest & cfor, int mergeIndex1, int mergeIndex2, RulePtr mergeRule)
{

    assert(mergeIndex1>=0);
    assert(mergeIndex2>=0);
    this->mergeIndex1=mergeIndex1;
    this->mergeIndex2=mergeIndex2;
    this->mergeRule=mergeRule;
    assert(mergeRule->getChildrenTypes().size()==2);

    assert(mergeIndex1!=mergeIndex2);

    mergeNode1=cfor.getTree(mergeIndex1);
    mergeNode2=cfor.getTree(mergeIndex2);

    assert(cfor.getTree(mergeIndex1)==mergeNode1);
    assert(cfor.getTree(mergeIndex2)==mergeNode2);
    mergeResult=mergeRule->applyRuleMarshalledParams(marshalParams(mergeRule));


    if(mergeResult==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    mergeResult->declareOptimal(false);

            adjustCostDeltaForNodeAddition(mergeResult,cfor);
    adjustCostDeltaForNodeRemoval(mergeNode1,cfor);
    adjustCostDeltaForNodeRemoval(mergeNode2,cfor);
    setTransProbFromDelta();
            cerr<<"mmcreat:"<<toString()<<endl;

}

virtual string toString()
{
    return mergeNode1->getName()+","+mergeNode2->getName()+"->"+mergeResult->getName();
}

virtual void applyMove(Forest & cfor)
{
    applied=true;
    // safety checks ... in the face of index updates
    assert(cfor.getTree(mergeIndex1)==mergeNode1);
    assert(cfor.getTree(mergeIndex2)==mergeNode2);


    cfor.deleteTree(mergeIndex1);// max to reduce #index updates in moves

    assert(cfor.getTree(mergeIndex2)==mergeNode2);

    cfor.replaceTree(mergeIndex2,mergeResult); // isSpanDisjo
}


virtual bool isInvalidatedOnDeletion(int index)
{
    if(index==mergeIndex1 || index==mergeIndex2)
        return true;


    return false;
}

virtual bool handleMove(int oldIndex, int newIndex )
{
    bool changed=false;


    if(mergeIndex1 == oldIndex)
    {
        mergeIndex1 = newIndex;
        changed=true;
    }

    if(mergeIndex2 == oldIndex)
    {
        mergeIndex2 = newIndex;
        changed=true;
    }



    return changed;
}
};
```

Comment: What's is the initial value of `mergeIndex1` in constructor `MergeMove()` ?

Comment: most likely your problem is with `shared_from_this`. however, re your point (1), don't use `new`. use `make_shared`.

Comment: Where did you see point #3 mentioned as a "standard guideline"? ... From what I've seen and read, even Herb Sutter has said that `shared_ptr` can be safely passed by reference (especially by `const` reference)...

Comment: @iammilind it is some non-negative value ... i do have an assertion to enforce that

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : full code runs into thousands of lines. I'm not sure how to clip it ... because I don't know where the problem is. BTW, if I don't care about efficiency, is `new` instead of `make_shared fine`?

Comment: as a start you might post the complete code of your class. that includes in particular the base class, where you are providing the *functionality that fails*. or perhaps not providing it. even if you don't care about efficiency, use make_shared instead of raw new. that way you avoid having raw pointers around.

Comment: *"Also, valgrind reports some invalid reads"* Debugged this? This is information crucial if the code base is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fixed the segfault. Also, valgrind does not report invalid read anymore. But I'm not sure why it was segfaulting earlier. Probably, my assumption in second line of second point in the question was wrong -"But I have passed *this to some functions taking a reference - I guess it should be fine."

previously, Move::applyMove was declared as

```
virtual void applyMove(Forest & cfor)=0;
```

I made a wrapper and made sure all calls use the wrapper.

```
virtual void applyMove(boost::shared_ptr<Forest> cfor)
{
    applyMove(*cfor);
}
```

All Forest objects in my code are dynamically allocated and managed by `shared_ptr`

Correspondingly, my Forest::applyMove(int) changed from

```
void applyMove(int index)
{
    Move::SPtr selMove=moves.at(index);
    selMove->applyMove(*this);
}
```

to

```
void applyMove(int index)
{
    Move::SPtr selMove=moves.at(index);
    selMove->applyMove(shared_from_this());
}
```